# how to run multiple instances of jvm on a vps

Tags: java, jvm, vps

I am running a java virtual machine on my virtual private server. a single instance runs fine but when I try to run more then one instance I get an error telling me that it cant create a new instance of jvm. I am guessing its because my heap size is not big enough, but when I try to up my Xms and Xmx the jvm wont run at all. is there a way that I can run multiple instances of jvm using tomcat on my vps? Is this a problem cause I am trying to run multiple jvms from the same browser?

Comment: you want to run multiple instances of jvm or you want to run multiple instances of tomcat on  your VPS?

Comment: @Balwinder Singh I want to run multiple instances of jvm on my vps.

Comment: Correct me if I got this wrong. You want multiple instances of jvm but want to use single tomcat. That's what you want? Also, why do you need multiple instances of JVM?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh well I mean if I can start multiple instances of tomcat to run a single jvm that would work for me to. Either way the end product needs to run multiple instances of jvm. I need to run multiple instances of jvm because my boss told me I need to the rest of the information of why I need to I don't have.

Comment: It may help if you post the error you're getting.

Comment: If you just want to run multiple instances of tomcat on same server, then you can look into http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server/. It might be little outdated but the idea remains the same, play around with ports

Comment: @BalwinderSingh that didn't fit my needs what I need is the jvm to be ran multiple times without having to edit files to get it to run.

Comment: @misterdeveloper and why do you need so? I am struggling to understand the practical purpose of it